Chrome extensions: Not working background.js
I used the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener and chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener functions to check if the page has finished loading.
For testing, I tried to page refresh, page naviage. But my code doesn't work.
What do I need to fix?
manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Tab Events Logger",
    "version": "1.5",
    "description": "Logs tab update and activation events",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
      }
    }
  }

background.js:
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    console.log("Tab updated:", tabId, tab.url);
    console.log("Change Info:", changeInfo);
});
  
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    console.log("Tab activated:", activeInfo.tabId);
});

